# What does it mean to use Ember.K in an if statement? What are some other common ways of using Ember.K?

Tags: ember.js

[Ember.K](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/3b60016c2b6b38646d954014d10f74fcfe1a3d54/packages/ember-metal/lib/core.js#L101) is an empty function, simply containing `return this`.

I observed it used in an if statement of a filter function for saving changes to EmberData. This is the [filter function](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L668-L670):

```
    if (adapter.shouldSave(record)) {
      filteredSet.add(record);
    }
```

In adapters (such as [localstorage  adapter](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter)) that lack their own implementations of `shouldSave()`, the [generic `shouldSave()`](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L689) of just `Ember.K` is used. So does it mean that the if statement basically turns into:

```
    if (true) {
      filteredSet.add(record);
    }
```

and the `record` is always added to the `filteredSet`.

Please correct me if I'm wrong.

---

What are some other uses of Ember.K?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So does it mean that the if statement basically turns into `if (true)...`:

Yep, that's exactly what it means.

> What are some other uses of Ember.K?

That's basically it. Think of `Ember.K` as a placeholder used in a base class when defining hooks that should be defined by child classes. Like the `activate` and `deactivate` hooks in [route.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v1.0.0-rc.6/packages/ember-routing/lib/system/route.js#L159-L173)